# Regular expressions in XSLT

Tags: regex, xslt

Been struggling to find a nice list of regex that is used in XSLT. Specifically looking for 'greater than', 'smaller than', 'equal to' etc regex.

If anyone can push me in the right direction it would be of great help.
Thanks very much!

Comment: What kind of data are you going to compare? What do you mean by _'greater than' regex_?

Comment: Are you trying to parse XSLT with regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the XSLT 2.0 regex dialect, the characters <, =, and > do not need to be escaped at the regex level. But of course < needs to be escaped at the XML level, using `&lt;`

Answer (score -1):

If my understanding is correct,

Regex to match the `>, <, =` and soon

```
\>
\<
\=
```

use `\` before a character to match